# create a custom field which is allowing multiple values using custom module

Tags: entities

I created custom content type and one custom field(text) successfully. But my requirement is, my custom field should allow to add multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

for unlimited set the cardinality to -1  `'cardinality' => -1`

example:

```
function _namecards_namecard_installed_fields() {
  $t = get_t();
  return array(
    'namecards_namecard_phone' => array(
      'field_name' => 'namecards_namecard_phone',
      'label' => $t('Phone'),
      'type' => 'text',
      'cardinality' => -1,
    ),
    'namecards_namecard_fax' => array(
      'field_name' => 'namecards_namecard_fax',
      'label' => $t('Fax'),
      'type' => 'text',
      'cardinality' => -1,
    ),
  );

}
```

Comment: What if I want to set minimum and maximum constraint on this field. For example user must enter at least 2 values and can maximum add 5 only.

Comment: @PankajJarial that needs to be a separate question. But you would simply do the logic in your form validation. [Take a look at line 83 to 89 here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/fapi_example/src/Form/SimpleForm.php).